The jmx data obtained from Flume is empty. How to get the correct result？
i set flume-env.sh JAVA_OPTS= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5445 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false.
i restart the service and exe the command of curl host:5445/jmx, the port of 5445 is connected，but i get empty from the url, result is curl: (52) Empty reply from server.
Is the url wrong?
